# How can I swap image locations in a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript and I'm creating a game where a user re-arranges a table of pictures by clicking.

The user clicks on one of the images in the table, then clicks another image in the table, and they are supposed to swap positions. I have to use javascript for this, so Ive created a 3x4 table and filled it with 12 images. Currently there are just two different types of images, but i plan to add more once I get the swap functionality done.

I added an event listener to all my images in the table, but I cannot get my alert to show up and give me the id of the picture. Also, I cannot get the images to swap locations once they are clicked.

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="hw3CSS.css" type="text/css"/>
   <title>Picture Scramble Game</title>
</head>

<script>

   function addEventListeners()
   {
      var images = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
      for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
      {
         images[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            images[i].addEventListener('mousedown', tagClick, false);
            alert('The id of the element you clicked: ' + this.id);
         };
      }
   }

   function swapImages("image1", "image2")
   {
      document.getElementsById("image1").src="image2";
      document.getElementsById("image2").src="image1";
   }

</script>

<body>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      addEventListeners();
   </script>

   <div id="table">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image1" src="mario.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image2" src="mario.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image3" src="mario.png" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image4" src="mario.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image5" src="mario.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image6" src="mario.png" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image7" src="luigi.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image8" src="luigi.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image9" src="luigi.png" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image10" src="luigi.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image11" src="luigi.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <img class="element" id="image12" src="luigi.png" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>

</body>
```

How can I at least get my alert to show up, telling me that the image was clicked, and what's a better way to go about swapping the images?

Comment: What are `tagClick` and `tags` ?

Comment: Your javascript contains syntax errors. You'll need to fix those before continuing as your script won't work.

Comment: Also, `addEventListeners` is called before the required HTML elements exist in the DOM. So that won't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set the call of `addEventListeners()` to the body unload event:

```
 <body onload="addEventListeners();">;
```

Also, your JavaScript seems to be totally wrong. Try something like this:

```
var rememberedElement = null;

function swapImages(image1, image2){
    var tmpSrc = image1.getAttribute('src');

    image1.setAttribute('src', image2.getAttribute('src'));
    image2.setAttribute('src', tmpSrc);

    rememberedElement = null;
 }

 function addEventListeners(){
     var images = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
     for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
     var image = images[i];
     image.addEventListener('click',function(event){
         if (rememberedElement === null){
            rememberedElement = event.target;
         }
         else {
            swapImages(rememberedElement, event.target);
         }
     },false); 
   } //for i
 }
```

This is untested and may contain some errors. It should give you a hint of what you can do.

Comment: Some variable to store the first clicked element to be able to swap the image with the second clicked image

Answer (score 0):

I think that's better to swap images at the dom level instead of just swapping the urls. That will also allow you to have all image attributes and specificities (including `alt` and `title`) being swapped.

```
function addEventListeners() {
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
    var selectedImage = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(selectedImage == null) {
                selectedImage = this;
            } else {
                // Getting tds containing images
                var selectedParent = selectedImage.parentNode;
                var thisParent = this.parentNode;

                // Detaching images from DOM
                // (it's optional because appendChild implicitly does it)
                //selectedParent.removeChild(selectedImage);
                //thisParent.removeChild(this);

                // Adding images to DOM
                selectedParent.appendChild(this);
                thisParent.appendChild(selectedImage);

                selectedImage = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick tip: `removeChild` is useless here. Appending a child to another element will move it there, thus removing it from the old parent.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You're right. I commented it (not removed) to make it easier to understand. Thank you.